# "make install" requires specific version of python, am I setting my source wrong?

Tags: python, makefile

This is my first time using the `make install` command. The program I'm trying to install uses python 2.7, and my environment normally has python 3.6. I'm using Linux.

I thought using `conda create -n oldpython python=2.7`, followed by `source activate oldpython`, then `make install` would allow the program to install. However, after using `make install` I get the error

`SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
make: *** [check_dep] Error 1`

Since it's `missing parentheses in call to 'print'`, maybe I'm not loading up python 2.7 like I thought?

Comment: Print in python2 doesn't use parenthesis for prints, that's a python3 feature, what program are you trying to install by the way?

Comment: It's a little program a colleague created for our company. I know python2 doesn't use parentheses for print, which is why I know the `make install` isn't working with python2, it's working with the default python3. I know I have python3 installed because when I run `python` it gives me the version as 3.6

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Linux, edited to include that.

Comment: Ok so if conda is giving you problems, first try and use the [virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237415/python-2-instead-of-python-3-as-the-temporary-default-python) if that doesn't work, then we'll try do a symlink.

Comment: That works! Thanks!